# Scikit Ordinary Least Squares Constant Term Not Working

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from random import randint

temp=[]
for i in range(0,100):
    r = randint(0,100)
    x=r*r+10*r+1000
    y=r
    temp.append([x,y])

tempX = [p[0] for p in temp]
tempY = [p[1] for p in temp]

trainX = tempX
trainY = [[1, y, y*y] for y in tempY]

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(trainY, trainX)

print regr.coef_
```

Running the above code gives me the following output

`[  0.  10.   1.]`

The Ordinary Least Squares gets the coefficients of r*r and r correctly. They match the coefficients provided by me on line 7.

**Why does it not get the constant term correctly?**

**How do I make it work the way I want to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LinearRegression`, an intercept term is automatically added. You can view this intercept term with:

```
print regr.intercept_ # 1000.0
```